# Linq join 2 entities on a single field and return the matching entries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm working with a database where the foreign key has been forgotten and I cannot modify it.

The idea is to "follow" this foreign key with a Linq query, what I managed to do is :

```
MY_ENTITY_CONTEXT ctx = new MY_ENTITY_CONTEXT();
List<MY_ENTITY_OBJ1> objs1 = ctx.OBJ1.Where(mycondition).ToList();
List<MY_ENTITY_OBJ2> objs2 = ctx.OBJ2.Where(x=>x.objs1.Select(o=>o.FieldToJoin).ToList().Contains(x.FieldJoined)).ToList();
```

However, I'm certain that this isn't the best way to do and I'm sure that there are any better operator but I can't find which one. I wanted to use `.Join()` but for me, as in SQL, it's used to have a synthetic representation of two tables intersected on a property.

Do you know which operator would suit best to my case ?

Thanks !

Comment: `foreign key has been forgotten`? what does that mean?

Comment: you can use `.union()` to merge both List.

Comment: Ric : In the database, there are no constraint defined as 'foreign key' and then, when I update my edmx, there are no navigation property between my two objects. I can do it manually but it involves to re-create the nav property everytime the edmx is updated..

gauravbhavsar : Union isn't supposed to merge two list of the same type ?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a regular join statement:

```
from o1 in ctx.OBJ1
join o2 in ctx.OBJ2 on o1.FieldToJoin equals o2.FieldJoined
where o1 == <mycondition>
select o2
```

You can even define associations between entities when there's no foreign key in the database. The only requirement is that one entity refers to another entity's primary key (more precisely: the primary key that is known to EF). So possibly you could define a navigation property like `OBJ1.OBJ2s`.

Answer (score 0):

Try these solutions

This will search if `keyword` appears anywhere in `ArticleContents`.

```
var aa = ctx.OBJ1.Where(a => context.OBJ2.Any(b => 
                                     b.ArticleContents.Contains(a.keyword))).ToList();
```

This will search the exact matching of `ArticleTitle` with `Title`

```
var cc = ctx.OBJ1.Where(a => context.OBJ2.Select(b =>
                                     b.ArticleTitle).ToList().Contains(a.Title)).ToList();
```

I changed column names just for clear understanding and it will fit in your scenario.